# snapcraft stuck on instance status preparing

Tags: snap, lxc, lxd

I'm trying to follow the [snapcraft tutorial](https://snapcraft.io/docs/create-a-new-snap) on Ubuntu 22.04.

I've installed and initialized lxd and snapcraft. When I run the snapcraft command it seems to hang on instance setup and eventually fails. Here is some of the output when running with `--verbosity=trace`:

```
2023-11-09 07:16:22.734 Executing on host: lxc --project snapcraft config get local:base-instance-snapcraft-buildd-base-v30--ebe48dea8e0ee8ae59ed user.craft_providers.status
2023-11-09 07:16:22.797 Instance status: PREPARING
2023-11-09 07:16:22.797 Executing on host: lxc --project snapcraft config get local:base-instance-snapcraft-buildd-base-v30--ebe48dea8e0ee8ae59ed user.craft_providers.timer
2023-11-09 07:16:22.865 Timer: 2023-11-09T14:00:53.448461+00:00
2023-11-09 07:16:25.867 Executing on host: lxc --project snapcraft info local:base-instance-snapcraft-buildd-base-v30--ebe48dea8e0ee8ae59ed
2023-11-09 07:16:25.929 Instance info: {'Name': 'base-instance-snapcraft-buildd-base-v30--ebe48dea8e0ee8ae59ed', 'Status': 'RUNNING', 'Type': 'container', 'Architecture': 'x86_64', 'PID': '1025872', 'Created': '2023/11/09 06:59 MST', 'Last Used': '2023/11/09 06:59 MST', 'Resources': {'Processes': '5', 'CPU usage': {'CPU usage (in seconds)': '0'}, 'Memory usage': {'Memory (current)': '20.95MiB'}, 'Network usage': {'eth0': {'Type': 'broadcast', 'State': 'UP', 'Host interface': 'veth25d71a31', 'MAC address': '00:16:3e:c3:4d:46', 'MTU': '1500', 'Bytes received': '184.77kB', 'Bytes sent': '12.63kB', 'Packets received': '2805', 'Packets sent': '151', 'IP addresses': {'inet': '10.13.134.100/24 (global)', 'inet6': 'fe80::216:3eff:fec3:4d46/64 (link)'}}, 'lo': {'Type': 'loopback', 'State': 'UP', 'MTU': '65536', 'Bytes received': '0B', 'Bytes sent': '0B', 'Packets received': '0', 'Packets sent': '0', 'IP addresses': {'inet': '127.0.0.1/8 (local)', 'inet6': '::1/128 (local)'}}}}}
2023-11-09 07:16:25.930 Executing on host: lxc --project snapcraft config get local:base-instance-snapcraft-buildd-base-v30--ebe48dea8e0ee8ae59ed user.craft_providers.status
2023-11-09 07:16:25.997 Instance status: PREPARING
2023-11-09 07:16:25.997 Executing on host: lxc --project snapcraft config get local:base-instance-snapcraft-buildd-base-v30--ebe48dea8e0ee8ae59ed user.craft_providers.timer
2023-11-09 07:16:26.077 Timer: 2023-11-09T14:00:53.448461+00:00
2023-11-09 07:16:29.080 Executing on host: lxc --project snapcraft info local:base-instance-snapcraft-buildd-base-v30--ebe48dea8e0ee8ae59ed
2023-11-09 07:16:29.154 Instance info: {'Name': 'base-instance-snapcraft-buildd-base-v30--ebe48dea8e0ee8ae59ed', 'Status': 'RUNNING', 'Type': 'container', 'Architecture': 'x86_64', 'PID': '1025872', 'Created': '2023/11/09 06:59 MST', 'Last Used': '2023/11/09 06:59 MST', 'Resources': {'Processes': '5', 'CPU usage': {'CPU usage (in seconds)': '0'}, 'Memory usage': {'Memory (current)': '20.95MiB'}, 'Network usage': {'eth0': {'Type': 'broadcast', 'State': 'UP', 'Host interface': 'veth25d71a31', 'MAC address': '00:16:3e:c3:4d:46', 'MTU': '1500', 'Bytes received': '185.02kB', 'Bytes sent': '12.63kB', 'Packets received': '2811', 'Packets sent': '151', 'IP addresses': {'inet': '10.13.134.100/24 (global)', 'inet6': 'fe80::216:3eff:fec3:4d46/64 (link)'}}, 'lo': {'Type': 'loopback', 'State': 'UP', 'MTU': '65536', 'Bytes received': '0B', 'Bytes sent': '0B', 'Packets received': '0', 'Packets sent': '0', 'IP addresses': {'inet': '127.0.0.1/8 (local)', 'inet6': '::1/128 (local)'}}}}}
2023-11-09 07:16:29.154 Executing on host: lxc --project snapcraft config get local:base-instance-snapcraft-buildd-base-v30--ebe48dea8e0ee8ae59ed user.craft_providers.status
2023-11-09 07:16:29.192 Instance status: PREPARING
2023-11-09 07:16:29.192 Executing on host: lxc --project snapcraft config get local:base-instance-snapcraft-buildd-base-v30--ebe48dea8e0ee8ae59ed user.craft_providers.timer
2023-11-09 07:16:29.277 Timer: 2023-11-09T14:00:53.448461+00:00
2023-11-09 07:16:32.280 craft-providers error: Instance setup failed. Check LXD logs for more details.
2023-11-09 07:16:32.281 Full execution log: '/home/tyler/.local/state/snapcraft/log/snapcraft-20231109-071527.770857.log'
```

If I try to manually run those lxc commands here are the outputs:

```
> lxc --project snapcraft config get local:base-instance-snapcraft-buildd-base-v30--ebe48dea8e0ee8ae59ed user.craft_providers.status
PREPARING
```

```
> lxc --project snapcraft info local:base-instance-snapcraft-buildd-base-v30--ebe48dea8e0ee8ae59ed
Name: base-instance-snapcraft-buildd-base-v30--ebe48dea8e0ee8ae59ed
Status: RUNNING
Type: container
Architecture: x86_64
PID: 1025872
Created: 2023/11/09 06:59 MST
Last Used: 2023/11/09 06:59 MST

Resources:
  Processes: 5
  CPU usage:
    CPU usage (in seconds): 0
  Memory usage:
    Memory (current): 20.95MiB
  Network usage:
    eth0:
      Type: broadcast
      State: UP
      Host interface: veth25d71a31
      MAC address: 00:16:3e:c3:4d:46
      MTU: 1500
      Bytes received: 350.75kB
      Bytes sent: 13.45kB
      Packets received: 5454
      Packets sent: 158
      IP addresses:
        inet:  10.13.134.100/24 (global)
        inet6: fd42:a260:2383:2fef:216:3eff:fec3:4d46/64 (global)
        inet6: fe80::216:3eff:fec3:4d46/64 (link)
    lo:
      Type: loopback
      State: UP
      MTU: 65536
      Bytes received: 0B
      Bytes sent: 0B
      Packets received: 0
      Packets sent: 0
      IP addresses:
        inet:  127.0.0.1/8 (local)
        inet6: ::1/128 (local)
```

I did find a journal file in the lxd logs and this is the only suspicious thing I found:

```
Nov 09 08:12:36 snapcraft-my-snap-name-on-amd64-for-amd64-25328813 systemd-journald[34]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/a6a2964c01d142b58bcfed58764c138e) i>
Nov 09 08:12:36 snapcraft-my-snap-name-on-amd64-for-amd64-25328813 systemd[35]: modprobe@configfs.service: Executable /sbin/modprobe missing, skipping: No suc>
Nov 09 08:12:36 snapcraft-my-snap-name-on-amd64-for-amd64-25328813 systemd[36]: modprobe@fuse.service: Executable /sbin/modprobe missing, skipping: No such fi>
Nov 09 08:12:36 snapcraft-my-snap-name-on-amd64-for-amd64-25328813 systemd-remount-fs[40]: mount: /: cannot remount /dev/root read-write, is write-protected.
Nov 09 08:12:36 snapcraft-my-snap-name-on-amd64-for-amd64-25328813 systemd-remount-fs[38]: /bin/mount for / exited with exit status 32.
Nov 09 08:12:36 snapcraft-my-snap-name-on-amd64-for-amd64-25328813 systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 09 08:12:36 snapcraft-my-snap-name-on-amd64-for-amd64-25328813 systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 09 08:12:36 snapcraft-my-snap-name-on-amd64-for-amd64-25328813 systemd[1]: Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just been having the same problem. Did you install snapcraft with `--edge` as per the tutorial?

This was causing the problem for me so I did the following and could then build snaps again:

```
sudo snap remove snapcraft
sudo snap install snapcraft --classic
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this in the future, there is also this other possible cause for the above behavior.

If you have Docker installed on your machine, please be aware of Docker's misbehavior and try the following to fix the networking: [Prevent connectivity issues with LXD and Docker](https://documentation.ubuntu.com/lxd/en/latest/howto/network_bridge_firewalld/#prevent-connectivity-issues-with-lxd-and-docker).

You can quickly check that the fix works from a LXD container by pinging 8.8.8.8.